# GoodData API: format of the recurrence value

Tags: api, gooddata

I'm trying to schedule sending a dashboard through the API:
http://docs.gooddata.apiary.io/#reportsanddashboardsbyemail

The parameter for setting how often the emails should be sent has some weird format:

```
"recurrency": "0:0:0:1*12:0:0",
```

I would expect it to be a cron expression, never seen this format before. Anyone has an idea what the numbers mean and how to put it together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find specification [here](http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip-5.56/lib/Date/Manip.pod)

For example:

```
0:0:2:1:0:0:0 every 2 weeks and 1 day 
0:0:0:0:5:30:0 every 5 hours and 30 minutes 
0:0:0:2*12:30:0 every 2 days at 12:30 (each day) 
0:0:0:1*2,4,6:0:0 every day at at 2:00, 4:00, and 6:00 
0:0:0:2*12-13:0,30:0 every other day at 12:00, 12:30, 13:00, and 13:30 
0:1:0*-1:0:0:0 the last day of every month
*1990-1995:12:0:1:0:0:0 Dec 1 in 1990 through 1995 
3*1:0:2:12:0:0 every 3 years on Jan 2 at noon 
0:1*0:2:12,14:0:0 2nd of every month at 12:00 and 14:00
```